# Firebase cloud functions bundled with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions

I've been stuck for a while trying to make a **webpack** build for my cloud functions files.

My project structure:

```
ROOT

- FUNCTIONS
  - DIS
    - bundle.js // THIS SHOULD BE GENERATED BY WEBPACK
  - SRC
    - myCloudFunction.js  // SOURCE CODE FOR A CLOUD FUNCTION
    - entryPoint.js  // ENTRY POINT FOR WEBPACK
  - index.js    
  - package.json

- SRC
  - App.js

.babelrc
firebase.json
webpack.prod.js    // THIS BUILDS FOR CLIENT (WORKING FINE)
webpack.server.js  // THIS SHOULD BUILD FOR THE SERVER (NOT WORKING)
```

My goal is:

- Write cloud functions files and the `index.js` in modern JS and transpile and bundle them with webpack (using the same `webpack` that I use to bundle my client code, but with another config file).

**myCloudFunction.js** (simple function logging some text)

```
module.exports = (req,res) => {
  console.log('myCloudFunction is executing...');
  res.status(200).send('From myCloudFunction...');
}
```

**entryPoint.js** (basically imports function's code and export them as cloud functions)

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const myCloudFunction = require('./src/myCloudFunction');

module.exports.myCloudFunction = functions.https.onRequest(myCloudFunction);
```

If I make the `index.js` exactly like my `entryPoint.js` it works just fine. But I want to bundle the files using webpack from the `entryPoint.js` and set the bundled result to my `index.js` file. Basically only 2 files will be bundled in this case (`entryPoint` and `myCloudFunction`).

I'm using webpack to bundle:

**webpack.prod.server.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  stats: 'verbose',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  entry: {
    app: './functions/src/entryPoint.js'
  },

  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './functions/dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  // externals: {
  //   "firebase-admin": true,
  //   "firebase-functions": true
  // },

  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals(),'firebase-functions', 'firebase-admin','firebase'],

  plugins:[
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.ON_SERVER': true
    }),
    new Dotenv()
  ],

  module: {
    rules:[
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },   
    ]
  }
};
```

I read that you shouldn't bundle node_modules to the backend, that's why I'm using the `externals` property.

**bundle.js** (the result bundle after running webpack with the config above)

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = "oFca");
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "4ouX":
/*!******************************************!*\
  !*** ./functions/src/myCloudFunction.js ***!
  \******************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = (req,res) => {
  console.log('myCloudFunction is executing...');
  res.status(200).send('From myCloudFunction...');
}

/***/ }),

/***/ "O8Wp":
/*!*************************************!*\
  !*** external "firebase-functions" ***!
  \*************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = firebase-functions;

/***/ }),

/***/ "oFca":
/*!********************************!*\
  !*** ./functions/src/index.js ***!
  \********************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

const functions = __webpack_require__(/*! firebase-functions */ "O8Wp");
const myCloudFunction = __webpack_require__(/*! ./myCloudFunction */ "4ouX");

module.exports.myCloudFunction = functions.https.onRequest(myCloudFunction);

/***/ })

/******/ });
```

**IT SHOULD BE WORKING, BUT I'M GETTING THIS ERROR:**

I would expect to copy the contents of `bundle.js` and paste it to `index.js` and make it work. But when I do this, I get this error when I'm trying to serve the function. See the error line in the picture below.

```
>>> firebase serve --only hosting,functions

+  functions: Using node@10 from host.
+  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5001
i  functions: Watching "C:\Projects\test-ssr\functions" for Cloud Functions...
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: public
+  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000
!  ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at Object.O8Wp (C:\Projects\test-ssr\functions\index.js:110:20)
```

[image]

**QUESTION**

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

---

**UPDATE**

I've just found out that this fixes the problem, but I have no idea why this is necessary. I still would like some better understanding of this issue.

**webpack.prod.server.js**

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash:5].js',
    // filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './functions/dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'   // <--- THIS FIXED IT
  },
```

Comment: Any reason why you even need to use webpack here?  Functions works just fine without, as node lets you dynamically require any installed module, and the total size of the code you're deploying shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: I'm trying to implement SSR for some routes (for crawlers that I'll detect based on User-Agent). So I'm willing to write my app's code in a way that it works both on client and on the server. In this [SSR tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82tZAPMHfT4) on Firebase YT channel, he transpiles all of his app files and his `index.js` (functions folder) file using Babel. I thought it would be weird to transpile like 300 files and replicate them into the functions folder. I thought it would be nicer to bundle them since I'm already using webpack for client. Am I on the right track here? Thanks

Comment: Personally, I don't see how it's any "nicer", in practical terms, to use webpack to deploy to Cloud Functions when everything will work as-is.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks a lot for your help, Doug! I'll follow your advice. It's infact necessary to transpile all of my files (written with `import / export` statements) in order to send them to the Node JS v10 environment, right? Like he did in the tutorial? Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't follow the tutorial.  If you're trying something new that isn't working the way you expect, please post another question with the details. node 10 language feature can be seen here: https://node.green/

Comment: @cbdeveloper - I'm trying to accomplish similar thing and stuck with the problem where the functions are not deploying after webpack since they are no longer defined in the top level/file scope but rather they are moved to a function by webpack. None of the tutorials cover that but so far it seem like it can't work like that. Have you made your webpack-ish build work fine? If so, could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118080/firebase-webpackbabel-functions-not-deploying

Comment: @virus hi! I actually gave up on that idea after Doug pointed out that infact I don't really need a bundled version of my code inside the Node runtime. Think about it: Webpack exists because the browser does not have a module system, at least [most of them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) don't. But Node.js has had it for a long time, so why bother bundling up your files if Node.js can handle them as modules just fine? Are you implementing SSR? Is that why you've though of using webpack? I'm using Babel to transpile, though, 'cause I'm using ES6 imports.

Comment: thanks @cbdeveloper! Got it. I need it because there is a hierarchy of models (ES6 classes) and I'm looking for a way to use those models in node resolving all imports in the model (which webpack does) and to make them compatible with node (which babel does) without being able to change the model related code. Thanks again for getting back on this! I seem to be on my way to making it work though I was hoping there is an easier way :)

Comment: Why Webpack is important to resolve your modules? I've had some trouble with resolving path aliases. Don't know if your doing that as well, but check out [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver) and its [docs](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/master/DOCS.md). It might help you to solve your problem using only Babel, instead of Webpack + Babel.

Comment: In case you're getting 'Handler is not a function' in the logs, use libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' instead. commonjs alone didn't work for me but comonjs2 did the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found, you need to set [`libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget) in order to build a webpack bundle that can itself be imported by another module outside the webpack build (e.g. from cloud functions).

It's a good idea to bundle your functions app using webpack for alot of reasons. As you've pointed out, it means you can compile the same code in a consistent way for different purposes - e.g. SSR and browser side. Other benefits:

- access to webpack loaders/plugins
- much better developer experience with HMR (that works better than the functions runtime's implementation)
- better performance for deployment and runtime (one or a few optimized chunks vs hundreds/thousands of unoptimised/unused files)

In any case, you might have an easier time using [webpack-cloud-functions](https://github.com/hedgepigdaniel/webpack-cloud-functions/) (of which I'm the author). It abstracts away much of the configuration you need to do that, including configuring the `libraryTarget`.