# Firebase webpack+babel functions not deploying

Tags: firebase, webpack, google-cloud-functions, babeljs

Is it possible to make firebase functions work with webpack and babel?

We need to reuse existing ES6 classes on server side which we can't edit so we need to transpile them to make it work in node.

Spent two days on the related tutorials but I'm hitting the problem where firebase can't seem to see functions declared in index.js after they were wrapped by webpack in a function.

here is a part of the resulting index.js:

```
(function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    var functions = __webpack_require__(/*! firebase-functions */ "firebase-functions");
    var admin = __webpack_require__(/*! firebase-admin */ "firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp();

    exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(function (req, res) {
      res.send({
        msg: "ok"
      });
    });

})
```

`exports.api = functions.https.onRequest` is not deploying in this case.

Is it ever possible to make firebase work with webpack and babel?

Comment: Could you help me understand why you need to use webpack and babel on a backend environment such as Cloud Functions?  The default runtime for CF is node 8, which is perfectly capable of running ES6 without any preprocessing or transpiling.  And the size of your function and its code doesn't much matter to CF.  Just let npm manage your dependencies and you should be OK.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson. Yes, the problem is that we have vue project for web app which has quite an hierarchy of model objects (ES6 classes with all those imports). We need to reuse those models now on server without being able to change the client code. And it doesn't work if we just through the new dependencies in the node project because of import syntax and the relative paths in the models. Webpack+babel however solves that, but introduces another problem I've described above. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, you might want to better explain specific problem you're running into because your question, as stated now, is just a "yes or no" question.  If you with a specific problem, you'll want to edit the question to explain what that is, else the question might get closed as too broad.  If you're looking for a general discussion or tips or tricks, try posting to a message board such as Reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: I will say that your function exports have to execute at the top level of the code. They can't be in a deferred callback.  I think you'll have an easier time with this if you start with the framework set up by the Firebase CLI, then layer in the dependencies and other code as needed, using only the minimum to get by (which means avoiding webpack and babel until you absolutely need them). Especially avoid webpack.  A transpiler should be relatively easy to set up, and the CLI has a template for TypeScript, if that helps.

Comment: "I will say that your function exports have to execute at the top level of the code. They can't be in a deferred callback" - thanks @DougStevenson, I guess that pretty much answers my question and gives the direction. So I need to find a way to keep the main index.js as is while applying webpack+babel only to the dependent models. And that seem to be the case based on what I get, but interesting that none of the related tutorials mentions any extra steps like that. Thanks again, now I know how I'll spend my weekend ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar challenge. I am not completely satisfied with how things are automated on the dev side (I will give more time on that during the next few days), but it is working indeed.

I will try to tell how I did it by changing code and instructions to remove unrelated complexity.

My main goal is not to manually maintain a "functions" folder with its own package.json as a separate project from my main one. Everything that resides in the root source code and some webpack magic should suffice.

1 - My entry point source code in a app.js file inside a /src/main folder. It reads like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { someProcessedOutputThatDependsOnExternalLibraries } from './my-code';

export const hello = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  functions.logger.info('Hello logs!', { structuredData: true });
  const output = someProcessedOutputThatDependsOnExternalLibraries(req)
  res.send(output).end();
});
```

2 - I want to export it to a /dist folder, so I have to set up that folder in the firebase.json file in the project root:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "dist"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
  }
}
```

3 - The package.json file in the root holds all the information needed for the project, especially the dependencies and useful scripts. Here some of the file content to illustrate.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "env:firebase": "firebase emulators:start",
    "build:firebase": "webpack --config webpack.firebase.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    "inquirer": "^7.3.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "xstate": "^4.15.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "generate-json-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.2"
  }
}
```

4 - Webpack is used to build a dist folder compatible with firebase specs. The webpack file below is almost entirely copied from this blessed [github gist](https://gist.github.com/mizchi/1929d54ff93e32217ec985094b473fd5#file-firebase-json-L1).

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const GenerateJsonPlugin = require('generate-json-webpack-plugin');
const pkg = require('./package.json');

const genFirebaseFunctionsPackage = () => ({
  name: 'functions',
  private: true,
  main: 'index.js',
  license: 'MIT',
  engines: {
    node: '14'
  },
  dependencies: pkg.dependencies
});

module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/main/functions.js',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  plugins: [new GenerateJsonPlugin('package.json', genFirebaseFunctionsPackage())]
};
```

5 - So, if I run `npm run build:firebase`, the dist folder is created with `index.js` and `package.json` files. The `dist` dir is now compatible with firebase CLI and emulator expectations.

But to run it in the local emulator, I still have to go to that folder and type "npm install" (that's the pain point I'm still trying to solve).

Comment: i get the error: [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read property 'PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL' of undefined

Comment: never had that one. maybe some package package.json dependencies are missing?! if you share a repo link here -- not sure i'm able -- but i would try to help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to bundle your functions app using webpack for alot of reasons:

- access to webpack loaders/plugins
- much better developer experience with HMR (that works better than the functions runtime's implementation)
- better performance for deployment and runtime (one or a few optimized chunks vs hundreds/thousands of unoptimised/unused files)

Many of the requirements are covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909938/2875622), but rather than making it all yourself, you might have an easier time using [webpack-cloud-functions](https://github.com/hedgepigdaniel/webpack-cloud-functions/) (of which I'm the author). It abstracts away much of the configuration you need to do that - e.g. `libraryTarget`, some of the `externals`, etc, and also provides reliable HMR for development out of the box.